# Isekai manga where MC reincarnates in a medieval village and has no power up or skill, he's only good at running

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm looking for a manga in which the main character (MC) reincarnates expecting magic or power ups, and finds himself weak and powerless.  He has to train in a garrison like a commoner soldier and he's only good at running.

The first monster appears as goblins attacking the village, with the goblins seemingly being unstoppable killing machines.  The main character hides in fear after seeing villagers and soldiers getting totally dismembered by them.  The goblins are only stopped by the commander of the soldiers who has some kind of lightning speed strike skill.

The MC is kinda dark, slim, and depressing. He was a high school athlete who injured his leg, and when he stopped being an athlete everybody gave up on him, family and friends. He drowned in sorrow, and got interested in video games, occult mangas, and isekais. Now I don't know if I'm mixing stories, but I remember he waited until his 30th birthday, at which point he expected to reincarnate in another world. At first it seems he did not, but he ended up reincarnating in a medieval village inside wooden walls as a younger version of himself, still powerless.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you remember the names of any characters or places or anything distinctive about the setting or art?

Comment: Not the one you're looking for, but mentioning [Gul](https://www.webtoons.com/en/action/gul/ep1-hunt/viewer?title_no=2617&episode_no=1) for having a protagonist who's really only good at running away.

Comment: I don't remember much about it, the mc is kinda dark slim and depressing, he was a high school athlet wich got an injury in one leg, stopped being an athlet and everybody give up on him family and friends, he drowned in sorrow, and got interested on videogames, occult mangas and isekais, now i dont know if im mixing story's, but i remember he waited til his 30 birthday, in wich he expected to reincarnate in another world, at first it seems not, but he end reincarnating in a medieval village inside  wodden walls in a younger version of himself, still powerless.

Comment: Possibly Magic Maker? There's a lot of differences, but you did mention you might be mixing up stories. MC abruptly reincarnates as a baby, with no magic. Explicit mention of age 30. But no backstory of him being an athlete. He reincarnates as a minor noble, not as a commoner. No mention of him being an especially good runner, but his sister is.

Answer (score -1):

[Nigoru Hitomi de Nani wo Negau - Highserk Senki](https://isekai.fandom.com/wiki/Nigoru_Hitomi_de_Nani_wo_Negau:_Highserk_Senki)

> Raizou Takakura, who died of a heart attack, was reborn in another
> world as the third son of a penurious farmer. He is known as Walm in
> his second life and he has been living as a soldier for the Highserk
> Empire, a small country currently being invaded by the surrounding
> large countries.
>
> To survive, Walm was forced to spend his days killing people left and
> right. The Highserk empire decided to point their fangs toward their
> enemy and plotted a great invasion battle against the principality of
> Myard as well as the Ferrius Kingdom. This led to Walm being covered
> in blood and witnessing the dying breaths of comrades and enemies
> alike, as well as learning of the fine line between life and death.

Comment: It would be useful if you could expand your answer by explaining what parts of this story match the OP's description.

Comment: @CDR - It doesn't seem a very good match, to be honest.